# How to sent postfix bounce to another SMTP server

Tags: email

How do I send postfix bounce to another SMTP server?

I have 2 postfix server (server_A and server_B).

I need the bounce generated from server_A sent to Internet by server_B.

Answer (score 0):

Half a year late... You should try adding this into your **main.cf** file located in your postfix directory:

```
notify_classes = bounce, 2bounce
bounce_notice_recipient = <server_B mail address>
2bounce_notice_recipient = <server_B mail address>
```

*Feel free to include other options in your **notify_classes** (eg. delay, policy, protocol, resource, software, data) if needed

Addition info: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes